# Crash tableView when voice over is on

Tags: objective-c, ios

i amusing a UItableView in an iOS projetct and it's working fine but when i turn on the voice over it crashes, it seems that this code return a null cell. Do you see any problem with my code :

```
-(UITableViewCell*) cellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath inTableView:(UITableView*) tableView {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TocCellView";
    UITableViewCell* cell =(UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Use apple technic explained here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TocCellView" owner:self options:nil];


        cell = self.tableViewCell;
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }

    if ([GraphicHelper isiPad]) {
        [self fillIPadCell:cell withBookPage:[self pageCorrespondingToIndex:indexPath] section:indexPath.section];
    }
    else {
        BOOL isEvenCell = (indexPath.row%2);
        BOOL isEvenHeader = (indexPath.section%2);
        [self fillIPhoneCell:cell withBookPage:[self pageCorrespondingToIndex:indexPath] forEvenCell:isEvenCell inEvenHeader:isEvenHeader];        
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a break point on this line:

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

If cell is null the it probably means your NIB couldn't be loaded and could be something as simple as  the wrong name for the NIB or you failed to make the proper connections in Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is when i don't activate the voice over , there is no crash and it's working.

Comment: You said the crash was from a result of a NULL cell being returned, if that is indeed the case then you've narrowed down your search already.  As it stands now, we don't know whether the issue is when the cell is queued or when it's loaded from the nib.